# Divs not moving with percentage in top value

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have three containers on the page inside of which are going to be filled with other things. However, I cannot seem to get the top to shift those containers with percentage so they resize properly. I am using position: relative for everything if that has any signifigance. Any help would be appreciated!

```css
                 position:relative;
                 height:100%;
                 width:100%
               }
               .picturebox {
                 position: relative;
                 border: solid white 1px;
                 min-width: 25%;
                 max-width: 25%;
                 height: 100%;
                 top: -350px;
               }
               .servicepic {
                 position: relative;
                 width: 100%;
                 top: 30%;
                 padding: 2%;
                 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                 box-sizing: border-box;
               }
               .middlecontainer {
                 position: relative;
                 border: solid white 1px;
                 min-width: 60%;
                 max-width: 60%;
                 top: 500%;
                 left: 25.1%;
               }
               .rightcontainer {
                 position: relative;
                 border: solid white 1px;
                 min-width: 14.75%;
                 max-width: 14.75%;
                 height: 100%;
                 top: -629px;
                 left: 85.2%;
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="bigbox">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Codes' Decoding</h1>
        <br>
        <h2 id="slogan">"Providing all of your web design needs"</h2> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="buttoncontainer">
      <a href="file:///C:/Users/Cody/Desktop/Websites/Practice.html">
        <div class="breadcrumb1">
          <p>Home</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="breadcrumb2">
        <div class="breadcrumb2">
          <p>Stuff</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="breadcrumb3">
        <div class="breadcrumb3">
          <p>Stuff</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="breadcrumb4">
        <div class="breadcrumb4">
          <p>Stuff</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="lightestl">
      <p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="nextlightestl">
      <p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="nextdarkestl">
      <p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="darkestl">
      <p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="lightestr">
      <p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="nextlightestr">
      <p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="nextdarkestr">
      <p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="darkestr">
      <p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="giantbox">
      <div class="picturebox">
        <img class="servicepic" src="http://exportbaltic.com/sites/default/files/styles/gallery_large_640/public/product-images/Export-Baltic.jpeg?itok=Cs0mNaSk">
      </div>
      <div class="middlecontainer">
        <p>hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightcontainer">
        <p>hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What output are you wanting and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to get it so the three divs are all at the same height. I have tried everything here so far and I have no idea what else to try

Comment: You have more than 3 divs, which 3 do you want the same height? also what to you mean by same height? Same vertical position on the page, or same size?

Comment: picturebox, middlecontainer, and rightcontainer are the three I would like the same height. By same height I mean same vertical position on the page

Comment: Do you want them horizontally aligned?

Comment: Yes I suppose that would be considered horizontally aligned. Basically I want the top of each of the divs to be the same height on the page

Answer (score 2):

To get this output: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djpianalto/u4zou6Lo/1/) I changed the `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;` on the divs in question, and then defined the positions for the three divs directly using `top: 0;`, `width: %;` depending on the needed widths of the divs so that they add up to 100%, I also removed margins so that they fit together evenly, and used `left: %;` where % is the percentage of page used up by divs to the left.

The problem with this method is it is not very dynamic. The best way to do what you are wanting is with a framework such as [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).

Answer (score 0):

my friend what you are doing is not good practice at all .

this is

```
 <div class = "lightestl"><p><br><br></p></div>
 <div class = "nextlightestl"><p><br><br></p></div>
 <div class = "nextdarkestl"><p><br><br></p></div>
 <div class = "darkestl"><p><br><br></p></div>
 <div class = "lightestr"><p><br><br></p></div>
 <div class = "nextlightestr"><p><br><br></p></div>
 <div class = "nextdarkestr"><p><br><br></p></div>
 <div class = "darkestr"><p><br><br></p></div>
```

instead of this you can put image or gradient CSS

using position relative for every thing also not good .

to make 3 container align with same size 
check flexBox

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/